# Parsing XML without quotes in Scala

Tags: xml, scala

I'm trying to parse some poorly generated xml code with scala that looks like this:

```xml
<contextfile concordance=brown>
<context filename=br-a01 paras=yes>
<p pnum=1>
<s snum=1> 
<wf cmd=ignore pos=DT>The</wf>
</s>
</p>
...
```

It's well structured, but as you can see there are no quotes surrounding any of the attribube values.  Simplying opening the file with the below Scala snippet throws a not so surprizing error:

```scala
val semCor = XML.loadFile(args(0))
```

throws

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "concordance".
```

I'd like to know how, if it at all possible, to setup the scala xml parser to correctly parse this input as if there were quotes surrounding the attribute values.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Erm, is there no way to change the XML instead? It would certainly be easier, and keep the XML up to standards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible to configure the parser to that extent in Scala. However, since your XML is malformed, you could use an HTML tidy library such as [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) or [TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) to tidy your XML first and then parse it with Scala XML. Or just get the data you want from the XMl using JSoup directly.

Comment: That's what I expected, but was not hoping for.  Thanks for the tidy libraries, I'll see how they handle my input files.

Comment: For the record, [TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) was **exactly** what I was looking for.  It auto added the much needed quotes.  Thanks @Matthew!

Answer (score 2):

Why do you refer to this as XML? It isn't. You might as well refer to a Scala program as a C# program. No XML parser will make any sense of it at all. You are using a completely proprietary format for your data interchange, and you have two choices: switch to using XML instead, or write a completely proprietary parser for it.

Comment: Because it **is** xml, it simply has a systemstemic set of syntax errors.

Comment: @fozziethebeat It is not XML because it doesn't follow the XML specification. At best it is "would-be XML". Where Mike is going is that it can be dangerous to work with a format that is poorly specified, and so it would be better to fix the source of the problem and actually use XML, or make sure you specify your format clearly. But then it won't be XML.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to configure the parser. Your parser won't accept "not well formed" XML. Maybe you should consider a first pass to add the quotes. In a general case, it's not possible to know how to deal with this problem, but it can be very easy in specific case, for example if attribute values dont contain any whitespace, quote, "&" or "<" characters.